# Closure set of closure set intersection - formal languages

Tags: formal-languages

Can we say...
Given L1 and L2.

Is the following true?
$$
L_{1}^{*} \cap L_{2}^{*} = (L_{1}^{*} \cap L_{2}^{*})^{*}
$$

I think it is true but I can't be sure. What permutation of either wouldn't be contained in each other. Sorry I don't know how to format on Math Exchange to make things look better.

-Steve

Comment: What exactly does your * operator mean? Are you talking about Kleene-star? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star

Comment: Yeah that's it. Sorry for not being clear. I haven't seen any other definitions of a closure set in formal languages.

Comment: Cool I preemptively posted an answer. Not too difficult to prove, but you should verify it as it's 00:17 in Ireland!

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be a language of the free monoid $A^*$. The answer easily follows form the fact that $L = L^*$ if and only if $L$ is a submonoid of $A^*$.

Now $L_1^*$ and $L_2^*$ are submonoids of $A^*$ and hence their intersection is a submonoid of $A^*$. Thus $L_1^* \cap L_2^*$ is a submonoid of $A^*$ and it is equal to its own star.

Comment: I've never seen the term 'free monoid' before. I assume it's from this link? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid

Comment: Why can you say that an intersection of the two submonoids is a submonoid?

Comment: It is a general fact. The intersection of two submonoids of a monoid is a monoid. Maybe you could try to prove this yourself, this is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Left to right is easy, because the set closure operator preserves all elements of the set. So now it's left to prove the right-to-left case. For this, assume an element $u$ in $(L_1* \cap L_2*)*$. It is of the form $u_1u_2\dots u_n$ with each $u_i \in L_1*$ and $u_i \in L_2*$. Now, consider the case of $u_i \in L_1*$. Since this is true for all $u_i$, and the sets are closed under concatenation, then $u = u_1u_2\dots u_n \in L_1*$. Same for $L_2*$. So it's in the intersection, and we're done.